# SetTimer(NULL, NULL, UINT, NULL)

Tags: c++, winapi, timer

I am reviewing an MFC application that has the following line of code:

```
SetTimer(NULL, NULL, 50, NULL);
```

From the WinAPI docs:

```
UINT_PTR SetTimer(
  HWND      hWnd,
  UINT_PTR  nIDEvent,
  UINT      uElapse,
  TIMERPROC lpTimerFunc
);
```

> Parameters
>
> hWnd
>
> Type: HWND
>
> A handle to the window to be associated with the timer. This window
> must be owned by the calling thread. If a NULL value for hWnd is
> passed in along with an nIDEvent of an existing timer, that timer will
> be replaced in the same way that an existing non-NULL hWnd timer will
> be.
>
> nIDEvent
>
> Type: UINT_PTR
>
> A nonzero timer identifier. If the hWnd parameter is NULL, and the
> nIDEvent does not match an existing timer then it is ignored and a new
> timer ID is generated. If the hWnd parameter is not NULL and the
> window specified by hWnd already has a timer with the value nIDEvent,
> then the existing timer is replaced by the new timer. When SetTimer
> replaces a timer, the timer is reset. Therefore, a message will be
> sent after the current time-out value elapses, but the previously set
> time-out value is ignored. *If the call is not intended to replace an
> existing timer, nIDEvent should be 0 if the hWnd is NULL.*

I believe that this line of code is intended to create a 50ms timer (not replacing some existing timer), but I don't understand the effect of the hWnd parameter being NULL.

The documentation does not make it clear to me what happens when I call SetTimer with the hWnd parameter of NULL AND the nIDEvent parameter of NULL.

Questions:

1. What does hWnd == NULL do in SetTimer?
2. Does nIDEvent == NULL always imply that I want to create a new timer (whose ID will be returned by the call), and not 'replace' an existing timer?
3. Should we be capturing the return value from SetTimer, and have a corresponding `KillTimer(return_value)` when we exit this thread?

Comment: What's unclear about `if the nIDEvent does not match an existing timer then it is ignored and a new timer ID is generated`?

Comment: Passing `NULL` for the ID is actually a mistake; it's an integer, not a pointer. `UINT_PTR` is an integer wide enough to store a pointer.

Comment: @Alan Birtles - that part of the document is clear.  What is not clear (to me, anyhow) is what is the intent when both parameters are NULL.

Comment: Amolbdnilo - While the intent might be obfuscated by using NULL in the code, in the context of the code, NULL is a #define that is doing a text substitution to 0.  As part of reviewing this code I will change it to 0. (This is very old code)

Comment: I think rephrasing the last sentence can make it a little bit clearer: If the call is intended to create a new timer and `hWnd` is `NULL`, `nIDEvent` should be `0`.

Comment: What is unclear about "*If the call is not intended to replace an existing timer, **nIDEvent should be 0 if the hWnd is NULL**.*"? That is exactly what the code is passing in, which means the code intends to always create a new timer.

Comment: I'm really  not sure what anyone can add to the documentation that you've quoted to make the operation of that function any clearer. We would only be quoting from that very document, I think.

Comment: What is missing (in my opinion) is what happens when hWnd is null AND nIDEvent is 0.

Comment: I found another web post on this subject that said when hWnd is NULL, SetTimer ignores nIDEvent (and assigns its own nIDEvent and returns it).  Maybe that is what is actually happening.  Again, not clear to me from the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What does hWnd == NULL do in SetTimer?**

When `hWnd` is `NULL` the timer is not associated with a window. Think of it as a global independent timer in your thread or application.

**Does nIDEvent == NULL always imply that I want to create a new timer
(whose ID will be returned by the call), and not 'replace' an existing
timer?**

Yes. Please see this line:

> If the call is not intended to replace an existing timer, nIDEvent
> should be 0 if the hWnd is NULL.

**Should we be capturing the return value from SetTimer, and have a corresponding KillTimer(return_value) when we exit this thread?**

Yes. Please see this part:

> If the function succeeds and the hWnd parameter is NULL, the return
> value is an integer identifying the new timer. An application can pass
> this value to the KillTimer function to destroy the timer.

**The correct code is:**

```
UINT_PTR timerId = SetTimer(NULL, 0, 50, NULL);

// some code

KillTimer(NULL, timerId);
```

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to kill the timer immediately after "some code", it won't have a chance to fire until you go back to the event loop.  Save that timer ID in a place you can retrieve it later.

Comment: @mar The code illustrates how to properly use the API. It's not meant to be meaningful or useful.

Comment: @IInspectable too many people take things literally.  I don't want OP's next question to be "why doesn't my timer fire?"

Comment: @mar Unclear why you do not want that question. If it is well framed, well researched, and well written there's nothing wrong, really. This question is about the semantics of an API, and the code in this answer explains them sufficiently well, regardless of whether the code does something meaningful.

Comment: @IInspectable oh I don't mind another question, I just thought this was an important point that shouldn't be glossed over.  We don't want our advice to kill perfectly good working code.

Comment: In my case, the 'some code' is a loop that lives a long time, and includes a message pump that checks for the timer.  The first part of the answer clarifies what I was somewhat confused about (hWnd == NULL).